# How do I change the JVM used to run IntelliJ on Windows

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm

I have two Java JDKs installed on my workstation, with jdk1.6.0_41 in my path, and jdk1.7.0_21 available as well, but not in the path.

How can I configure IntelliJ IDEA 13 to use a particular JVM?  To be clear, I want to set the JVM used to run IntelliJ itself, not the SDK used for running my code.  I am running Windows 7 Enterprise Edition and launch IntelliJ 13.0.2 by running `idea64.exe`

I have set `JAVA_HOME` to point to jdk1.7.0_21 but according to the About box it is using jdk1.6.0_41.

[This FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-197) on the JetBrains web site describes how to do this for Mac, but not for Windows.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14083813/274350) suggests using the `IDEA_JVM` environment variable for Ubuntu 12, but I have tried that and it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With newer versions the environment variables are ignored. Instead there is a new action "Choose Boot Java Runtime". The easiest way to get to it is via "Find Action" Ctrl+Shift+A.

You can also edit the setting via the `.jdk` file in your user configuration directory, e.g. `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.3\idea64.exe.jdk`. This is a plain text file containing only the path to the JDK.

It is not recommended to do this, and you should use the JDK that is bundled with IDEA.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have another setting that is overriding your JAVA_HOME

From [Jetbrains docs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under):

> idea64.exe uses this JDK search sequence:
>
> IDEA_JDK_64 environment variable
>
> ..\jre64 directory
>
> system Registry
>
> JDK_HOME environment variable
>
> JAVA_HOME environment variable

Comment: Excellent, setting IDEA_JDK_64=%JAVA_HOME% works for me.  There is probably a setting in the registry pointing to the 1.6 JDK, but I am not local admin on this machine so can't change this, and don't really want to.

Comment: The bin catalog contains both idea.exe and idea.bat . The latter uses the various environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

`CTRL`+`ALT`+`SHIFT`+`S` to go to `Project Structure`

Under `Platform Settings`, go to `SDKs`.

Use the `+` green icon to add a new `SDK` and set it to that one.

Comment: No, this is for setting the SDK to run my code, I want to set the JDK used to run IntelliJ itself, as reflected under Help - About.

Comment: fair enough, my mistake

Comment: I needed to switch between 32bit and 64bit for running two different java files in the same project and this worked best for me.